# jQuery Validate plugin, validate email address doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Since Dreamweaver has dropped Spry, I am looking for a simple alternative and am trialing the validate jQuery plugin. The problem I am having is that while the email validation doesn't work at all.

I have added the include files to the head:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

This is the code from the fields:

```
<div class="pure-control-group">
  <label for="First_Name">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="First_Name" id="First_Name" required />
</div>
<div class="pure-control-group">
  <label for="Last_Name">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="Last_Name" id="Last_Name" required />
</div>
<div class="pure-control-group">
  <label for="Email_Address">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" name="Email_Address" id="Email_Address" />
</div>
```

This is the validation code:

```
$("#form1").validate({
rules: {
  Email_Address: {
  required: true,
  email: true
  }
    }
});
```

Pretty simple. The first two fields validate correctly but not the email field.

Comment: Everything looks right to me. You may want to check the console for any javascript errors. Also, is the validate code beneath the form?

Comment: The validate code is placed just before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 1):

can you ensure you have the ID attached to your opening form tag?

ie: form id="form1"?

ahh just noticed you said the others do validate.

Comment: also I believe required should be the name of the class.  ie: class="required" though it doesnt seem to account for why this isnt working...

Comment: The id of the form is correct. I don't think that the first two fields do work, I think it's just the default behaviour of Chrome when you set a field to "required".

Comment: Worked it out, I had the jQuery include after the validate include. Thanks for the help.